# CreateNamedPipe and WaitForMultipleObjectsEx

Tags: multithreading, winapi

I have a thread which creates a named pipe like this:

```
CreateNamedPipe('\\\\.\\pipe\\dirwatcher', PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, PIPE_TYPE_BYTE, 1, 1, 1, 0, null);
```

I then spawn another thread called "poller" and this one has watches files. I want to make it wait for this pipe though, so I can interrupt the infinite poll.

I create the pipe in this poller thread like this:

```
pipe = CreateFile('\\\\.\\pipe\\dirwatcher', GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, null, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, null);
```

I then try to wait on this pipe like this:

For this case LP_HANDLES is an array with just one element, `pipe`:

```
rez_wait = WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(LP_HANDLES.length, LP_HANDLES, false, INFINITE, true);
console.log('rez_wait:', rez_wait);
```

However this doesn't wait at all, and immeidately return 0. I used overlapped flag in both creating the named pipe and connecting to it. Does anyone know how to fix this?

***Here is my code specifically, it is js-ctypes:***

Creating the pipe:
https://github.com/Noitidart/jscFileWatcher/blob/master/DirectoryWatcherWorkerSubscript.js#L91-L99

Getting the pipe in poller thread:
https://github.com/Noitidart/jscFileWatcher/blob/master/DirectoryWatcherPollWorker.js#L53-L64

Waiting on the pipe:
https://github.com/Noitidart/jscFileWatcher/blob/master/DirectoryWatcherPollWorker.js#L89

Thanks

Comment: Windows asynchronous I/O works differently to UNIX.  Instead of waiting for a ready condition and then issuing an I/O operation, you issue an I/O operation and wait for it to complete.  When you issue the I/O operation you can specify an event object to be signaled when the I/O is complete (or there are various other options) and then you wait on the event handle.  It is never meaningful to wait on a pipe handle.

Comment: Oh interesting, thanks @HarryJohnston - other then a timed interval - would you have suggestion on how I can interrupt my poll which is waiting on completion routines for `ReadDirectoryChangesW`? I need to interrupt the poll every time I need to add another path for it to watch.

Comment: If I've understood what you're doing correctly, using an event object instead of a pipe should work.

Comment: Oh I think I get it now, even object is in place of a pipe, super cool will look into that right away thanks!

Comment: ... personally, I would probably have the thread call SleepEx() in a loop, and use QueueUserAPC() whenever I wanted the thread to do anything special (like add another path).  More elegant.  But that's entirely a matter of taste, from a functional perspective either method is fine. :-)

Comment: Yes!!! It worked! I used `CreateEvent` and then `PulseEvent`, thanks so much! @HarryJohnston

Comment: You need to use `SetEvent` rather than `PulseEvent`.  `PulseEvent` will fail some of the time, for the reasons discussed in the documentation; infrequently, I think, but why take the risk?  Assuming there is only a single thread waiting on an auto-reset event, they will otherwise behave identically.

Comment: Thanks @Harry! That part made no sense to me. So does `SetEvent` modify my auto-reset event object in the same way? Meaning if the event is not being waited on it wont change its state away from false? These docs give me a headache haha so your input really helps me out! Yep correct assumption, single thread per `event` object.

Comment: That's true, `SetEvent` (unlike `PulseEvent`) will set the event to true even if no thread is waiting on it, i.e., the next time you issue the wait it will complete immediately.  But it is usually easy to deal with the case where the wait completes but there is no actual work to be done.  (Conversely, `PulseEvent` would typically lead to a race condition even if it worked properly; what if the thread has already stopped checking for new work, but not yet started waiting on the event?)

Comment: Ah thanks so much @Harry!

Comment: Hi there @HarryJohnston still didn't move away from `PulseEvent` because I can't deal with the case where the wait completes but no actual work was done. However I was thinking I can use `SetEvent` in similar way. How about everytime before I start the `WiatForMultipleObjectsEx` I should do a `ResetEvent`. Would this work corrrectly? (excuse me asking rather then trying, I am not understanding the race condition so not sure if this method will not have the race). Can `ResetEvent` work with an event created with `bManualReset` as false?

Comment: ResetEvent() will work with an auto-reset event AFAIK, but if you're going to be resetting the event manually, making it an auto-reset event is redundant.  But if you reset it just before waiting, there will certainly be a race condition: different behaviour if the event gets set just before you reset it as compared to just after you reset it.  It would typically be possible to fix that, but if you can't easily deal with the case where the wait completes immediately, you're not dealing with a typical architecture.  Please either email me or post a new question, with more details.

Comment: Thanks Harry! I'll post a question and link you from here I really appreciate your reply!

Comment: @HarryJohnston thanks very much I created a topic here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057933/setevent-resetevent-waitformultipleobjectsex-race-condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot wait for pipes using [`WaitForMultipleObjectsEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687028(v=vs.85).aspx) as stated within the remarks:

> The **WaitForMultipleObjectsEx** function can specify handles of any of the following object types in the *lpHandles* array:
>
> - Change notification
> - Console input
> - Event
> - Memory resource notification
> - Mutex
> - Process
> - Semaphore
> - Thread
> - Waitable timer

You have to use [`PeekNamedPipe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365779(v=vs.85).aspx) for this job (which doesn't wait if the pipe is empty) or you can simply do a blocking `ReadFile` on the pipe.

I've encountered the same problem a while ago and I've solved it by waiting for an event with `WaitForSingleObject` which I set if I've put something into the pipe. I had to do this since I had several pipes and only one "reader thread" which woke up by the event and the used `PeekNamedPipe` to check which pipe contains data (and I didn't want to create several "reader threads" which are blocked within a `ReadFile` call).

Anyway to me it is quite strange that you can wait for almost anything using `WaitForMultipleObjects` except pipes (which is **very** annoying!).

Comment: Pipes aren't really a special case.  You can't wait on file objects either, nor serial ports, window stations, desktops, or memory mappings.  Arguably, it's console input that's the odd one out, being the only I/O object you *can* wait on.  (Granted, it is awkward in a broader sense that the various different sorts of I/O each have their own semantics.)

Comment: Note that you need to be careful using an event to signal that you've put something in the pipe.  If the pipe's buffer isn't large enough to fit the data you're writing, you'll deadlock.  It is typically preferable to use asynchronous I/O if you don't want to have one thread per pipe.  (Or depending on your situation you could consider using shared memory or similar instead of pipes.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Agreed. It was a very controlled environment (and quick to implement) in which I've used the event with the pipes being empty most of the time and the "reader thread" reading as long as something is within the pipe before going to sleep again.

Comment: Thanks very much Lukas for this, I didn't see this and kept going the way @Harry pointed out, I ended up using `CreateEvent` and then sending a pointer to the even to the other thread (so shared memory I think this is called). I then added this event to the `WaitForMulipleObjectsEx` and then from the main thread I would call `PulseEvent` and it would trigger. I accepted this answer though as it answers the question on how to wait on a pipe, thanks for it!